# How to get the possible values of Priority, Difficulty through Automation API of Sparx EA

Tags: api, enterprise-architect

I am exploring the Sparx EA automation API. I am trying to get all fields metadata using the API.
For some fields like Status we can get all possible values (like - High, Medium, Low etc) using Repository.GetReferenceList(). But I am unable to find the possible value list for Priority and Difficulty.

I have checked the database and realize that initially it is not there in the any table. Also if we change the values list, it is coming in the database table.

Is there any way I get always get the possible values using API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository.GetReferenceList() function is enhanced in EA 11 to allows access to the Priority and Difficulty reference lists by passing parameters "List:PriorityType" or "List:DifficultyType".

For example:

```
Repository.GetReferenceList("List:PriorityType");
Repository.GetReferenceList("List:DifficultyType");
```

Comment: An undocumented feature? I don't see anything about those two in the help file: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/automation_and_scripting/reference3.html

Comment: Yes, they are not documented, but this feature came in the EA 11. It's not working with EA 10

Answer (score 3):

They are hardcoded **High**, **Medium** and **Low**

Comment: Are you just guessing or you have that from a credible (linkable?) source?

Comment: @xmojmr I'm not guessing. I know every table of the EA repository, and I've browsed to the registry bit quite a lot as well, and there's nowhere a table or key with these values. Most people consider me as a credible source when it comes to the guts of EA.

Comment: Nothing personal, your EA hacking career is impressive and I believe that hardcoding those values would work. But my norm for credible source when talking about the behavior of a software is source code, reverse engineered binary code, approved specification document, information published by the manufacturer, information from a former employee (insider's insights) and best of all it should be **verifiable**. "they are hardcoded.. period" does not fall into the above categories. Can you add some more supporting "repository" or "registry" info?

Comment: @xmojmr I just checked the sparx forum, and there are a few questions similar to this one. All of them come to the same conclusion in the end. It is hardcoded. I cannot add info about the repository or the registry if it is not there. If you want some kind of official answer you'll have to contact sparx support.

Comment: I agree with Geert, I've never found these anywhere either. Most of these permissible "enum" type values are stored in various tables in the database, but not these two. At the end of the day, what you enter into these fields in the GUI are strings anyway, and the database is just used to populate the drop-down list. In these particular cases, the list contents are instead hard-coded. So the short answer is "you can't retrieve these through the API" and the long answer is "you can't retrieve these at all." Well actually, that's the shorter answer. :)

Comment: Can confirm that those are hard coded. EA has quite a bit such strange stuff in its stomach.